# Using wait() without notify() when in synchronized code piece (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, synchronized

I wanted to know if it's possible to use wait() on a synchronized piece of code without using notify(), something like this:

```
wait_on(B):
    synchronized(B.monitor) {
    B.count--
        while (B.count > 0) { /* wait */ }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, if you want it to wait for all eternity for a notify.

Comment: How to you reckon to come out of the `wait()` state without a `notify()`? What you are doing is some what equivalent to killing the thread without actually doing it.

Comment: will it work without the synchronized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need notify or notifyAll to awaken the thread from its wait state. In your sample the code would enter the wait and stay there (unless interrupted).

Know the difference between wait, yield, and sleep. Wait needs to be called in a synchronized block, once the wait is entered the lock is released, and the thread stays in that state until notify is called. Yield returns the thread to the ready pool and lets the scheduler decide when to run it again. Sleep means the thread goes dormant for a fixed period of time (and from there it goes to the ready pool).

Make sure you call wait on the same object that you’re synchronizing on (here it’s B.monitor).

Comment: But that happens until all threads will enter this method, and the last one will cause the count to be 0, then it'll get out, which will make an automatic notify(), or am I wrong?

Comment: @MichBoy: there's no 'automatic' notify. once the counter goes to 0 then no more threads will enter the body of the while loop, that is all that will happen.

Comment: and if I get the synchronized off?

Comment: @MichBoy: are you trying to implement a counting semaphore? because java.util.concurrent has those already: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but different, will it work without the synchronized?

Comment: @MichBoy: hard to say without a clearer example. you need synchronized to call wait. you sure you want wait and not yield or sleep? because wait needs notify, it's about inter-thread communication.

Answer (score 0):

No! Only option is to wait with a timeout, which surely will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `/* wait */` into a call to `wait()`, and no one will call `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, then this thread will never wake up...

Answer (score 0):

If it is a barrier that you want, you will need to notifyAll your other threads:

```
wait_on(B) {
    synchronized(B.monitor) {
        B.count--
        while (B.count > 0) {
            B.monitor.wait()
        }
        B.monitor.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Regards,

Pierre-Luc